# Multiple slidetoggle divs change text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I have this code which reveals a profile div onclick and also changes the text of the clicked element. There are multiple instances of this.

```
<div class="show" data-target=".open1">View Profile</div>
<div class="info open1">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

When another div is opened the previously open div closes. However, the text on this still remains as 'close profile'. I'd like to change this so the text changes back too.

Any idea how I can do this?

```
var $bgs = $('.info');
var $show = $('.show');

$($show).click(function () {
    var $target = $($(this).data('target')).stop(true).slideToggle();
    $bgs.not($target).filter(':visible').stop(true, true).slideUp();

    $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).text(function(_, oldText) {
            return oldText === 'Close Profile' ? 'View Profile' : 'Close Profile';

        });

    });
})
```

Comment: you don't need to re-wrap `$show` in `$()` - it's already a jQuery object

Comment: no need of inner `.click(`. just check the text and update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this:

```js
var $bgs = $('.info');
var $show = $('.show');

$show.click(function () {
    var $target = $($(this).data('target')).stop(true).slideToggle();
    var oldOpened = $bgs.not($target).filter(':visible');
    oldOpened.stop(true, true).slideUp();
    if(oldOpened.length > 0){
      var tempClasses = $(oldOpened).attr("class");
      var oldOpenClass = $.trim(tempClasses.replace("info",""));
      var oldOpenerDiv = $("div[data-target='."+oldOpenClass+"']");
      
      $(oldOpenerDiv).text(function(_, oldText) {
        return oldText === 'Close Profile' ? 'View Profile' : 'Close Profile';

       });
    }
  
   $(this).text(function(_, oldText) {
      return oldText === 'Close Profile' ? 'View Profile' : 'Close Profile';

   });
})
```

```css
.info{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show" data-target=".open1">View Profile</div>
<div class="info open1">Lorem ipsum 11</div>
<div class="show" data-target=".open2">View Profile</div>
<div class="info open2">Lorem ipsum 22</div>
<div class="show" data-target=".open3">View Profile</div>
<div class="info open3">Lorem ipsum 33</div>
```

Comment: That's sorted it. Thanks a lot for that

Answer (score -1):

```js
var $bgs = $('.info');
var $show = $('.show');

$show.click(function() {
  var $target = $($(this).data('target')).stop(true).slideToggle();
  $bgs.not($target).filter(':visible').stop(true, true).slideUp();


  $(this).text(function(_, oldText) {
    return oldText === 'Close Profile' ? 'View Profile' : 'Close Profile';

  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show" data-target=".open1">View Profile</div>
<div class="info open1">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: Why the `$($show)`?? Also `$($(this).data('target'))`. If you defined the `$show` just use it: `$show.click(function(){...});`

Comment: you are right @ding0_d. but his query is different, it is not about how he is writing his code. Still i have corrected it.

Comment: Thanks for this @Atul. I've implemented the amended code. When I open a second profile the previous one closes but it's still displaying the 'Close Profile' text. How am I able to get it to go back to 'View Profile'?